# Moving tensor products inside homs

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

Suppose that $(\mathcal C, \otimes, I)$ is a closed symmetric monoidal category with $\hom(A,B)$ the hom-sets and $[A,B]$ the internal hom (where $[A,-]$ is right adjoint to $-\otimes A$).  Is there always a map $[A,B]\otimes C \to [A,B\otimes C]$?  Are there additional hypotheses needed to get such a map?

The map exists in $R$-mod, where $R$ is a commutative ring.  However, I am having trouble finding a purely categorical justification for its existence (unlike, say, the evaluation map $A\otimes [A,B]\to B$, which is the image of the identity map under a hom-tensor adjunction $\hom([A,B],[A,B])\to \hom([A,B]\otimes A,B)$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A map $[A,B]\otimes C\to[A,B\otimes C]$ is the same as a map $A\otimes[A,B]\otimes C\to B\otimes C$, and you have one $A\otimes[A,B]\to B$.

Comment: (Up to permutations of factors)

Comment: Now I feel a bit silly.